# How can i restore a deleted inbox in Outlook?

Tags: windows-xp, email, microsoft-outlook, inbox

I wanted to add a second account in Outlook 2003.  So, I went to ***tools >> E-mail Accounts >> add a new e-mail account***. I managed to connect to the second account.  However, now I can't see my first account anywhere. The Inbox contains only mail from the second account that I just added. Is my first account lost? Is there a way to restore it because I really need these mails?

Comment: Did you create a new profile?  

Is this an Exchange account?

Comment: What type of email account is the second one? Is it another Exchange account? Or is it a Gmail, Hotmail, or Yahoo type of email account?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new account in Outlook does not delete the old account(i.e. including emails, tasks and calander) unless you did some mistake

So either you have created a new profile, which you can check it by accessing control panel > mail > profiles or you did removed the old account and added another one, for which you can look for the old .pst file